# How do I edit events in "react-big-calendars"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-big-calendar

I want a clickable functionality where on clicking over the events on the calendar I am allowed to edit the dates or the event title.

Is it possible to do so with "react-big-calendar"?
If not can you suggest some other packages which does?

```
<Calendar
    localizer={localizer}
    events={allEvents}
    startAccessor='start'
    endAccessor='end'
    views={['month']}   
/>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCDVT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onSelectEvent={handleEventSelection} this prop can help you track whenever any event is clicked

You can use this code.

```
const handleEventSelection = (e) => {
  console.log(e, "Event data");
};
```

[Link for reference](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-onSelectEvent)